# Strange serial comms where data sent has missing characters using Arduino UART

Tags: serial

I have an Arduino Uno that sends data to the Raspberry Pi over UART.

But a lot of the time, I am finding that some of the data is missing.
For example, it supposed to send:

```
LCD:Sunday 01-Jan 08:39
```

But a lot of the time I get:

```
  D:Sunday 01-Jan 08:39
```

Ignore the fact the date and time is wrong. I've just not set the date and time and it resets every time you turn the power off.

I have searched the entire code base, I can't find anything that tells it to send it as `D:Sunday 01-Jan 08:39`

The alarm panel uses one wire serial interface so he uses software serial to send and receive commands to the panel. This appears to work.

The arduino uses it's hardware serial port to send data to drive the web interface. This is where am having strange data communication

As far as I know the only time the raspberry pi sends data is to initialise data communication by asking for the status of the alarm panel and when you send commands from the web interface to the panel. Once comms has been established, the PI keeps pulling the status of the panel to the PI.
The initialisation works fine which is why I think the problem is on the sending side.

So I turned off the server for the web interface. Then I manually entered the commands into the terminal attached to the uno, I get the same problems. So that tells me it is the sending side. The pi can't affect the communication if if the server application isn't on.

I have just noticed am seeing left over characters from previous transmissions

```
12:58:03.338 -> LCD: Sunday 01-Jan 01:04
12:58:03.498 -> LCD: Sunday 01-Jan 01:05
12:58:03.545 -> LED:...........P
12:58:04.337 -> +nday 01-Jan 01:04 **shud be just +**
```

Any idea what could be the cause? Is the proper solution to implement so kind of software flow control like you have in rs232?

Here is the source code to the Arduino and raspberry pi
[source code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FwHQKBR0MWOxg0fePdGDS65ctKSNSLHa/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: So is it always the first two characters?  Is it ever correct?  This is a software issue.  What happens if you send *xxLCD:Sunday 01-Jan 08:39*

Comment: I thought so. it sometimes is correct. but it's always the first two characters. weird. but like I say no where in the code does it tell the arduino to send it like that. I used the search function to look through all the files associated with the firmware. Weird its also consistent it happens every so often. Thanks for your help I'll have to debug it myself since nobody can run the firmware without the hardware attached to the Arduino. You're not going to purchase a Accenta G4 panel then you need the optocoupler interface between the panel and the arduino.

Comment: It is a code issue.  My advice is to kludge it with dummy characters at the start for now.  At some point, send 1 character and set up break points on receiving end to see what happens.  Try 2 characters, 3.  Are you adding (or subtracting) 1 to buffer size?  How does receiving UART handle characters?  Interrupts.  Kludge it, move forward and it will generally solve itself.

Comment: @Ageis I agree with Stainless. This is a driver problem. It's not uncommon for this very kind of bug to show up, because after some time delay the hardware buffers are empty. It could be in the sending side, if it doesn't properly re-initialize the serial port when given a new buffer to export over the wire. Or it could be on the receive side when the first characters of a new send then arrive. (There are software errors that can occur on either end.) Either way, it appears something is arriving. Just not a printable something. What is it, really? Or is that your hand-spacing there?

Comment: i think it's the sending side because i see it on the terminal windows attached to the uno

Comment: @Ageis That's not uncommon. Often, the transmit peripheral has a double-buffer. As soon as the first character is placed into it, the value is ***immediately*** moved to the out-going shift register, where it is clocked out. But the original latch is marked as now-empty and it needs a second byte, ***immediately***, to keep continuity. If the author isn't aware of this exceptional moment (different from the 3rd, 4th, etc. characters) then it is possible that something is improperly handled. Find a different library or write your own.

Comment: How have you connected the devices? Do you use Arduino functions on that side? What code/terminal/program you have on the Rasberry Pi side? Anything could be the problem if you don't give details what has been verified to work and what isn't.

Comment: The receiving side is a node js web application. It allows you to control an alarm panel via the internet. I am using a the serial monitor in the Arduino ide. I have connected the alarm panel to the Arduino and the Arduino to the PI.